# StartApp ADS provide better RPM integration and benifits

Tags: admob, ads, rpm, startapp

Is Start App ADS beneficial to add in the android app ? 
I have used google ads but getting lower request RPM.
Please guide how to integrate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can provide better request RPM in some cases depends which kind of ads you are using .
StartApp provide many type of ads for monetization. 
I have used it in my couple of applications
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=expert.apps.hindi.news&hl=en

You can create a startApp account using below link :
https://portal.startapp.com//#/signup?referredBy=rf86zzp

and then follow the guide about integration as below:
**github.com/StartApp-SDK/Documentation/wiki/Android-InApp-Documentation**